# whats the different between nibNameOrNil and ViewDidLoad methods?

Tags: iphone

whats os the difference between initWithNibName and ViewDidLoad methods ?
can i use them both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`initWithNibName` - is what **you** call to create a view controller from specified nib file.
`viewDidLoad` - is what **system** calls on your controller after the controller’s view is loaded into memory. You can implement this method to perform some additional initialization (which is not done in nib file)

Comment: thanks. i can use the initWithNibName for sound implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be confusing things here. nibNameOrNil is (usually) an argument name, frequently for -initWithNibName:bundle:. As such, it should be the name of your nib (.xib) file. -viewDidLoad is a method, and is called after your viewController has had it's view instantiated for the first time.